# jQuery animation zoom does not work with firefox and safari

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im using a custom slider i made, however i noticed the animation effect does not work in safari neither in firefox.

```
//Slider Function - item_class -> Your slide item class |  slides -> total number of slides | speed -> slider speed in ms (miliseconds)
//Slider Function - item_class -> A class do item do slider |  slides -> número total de slides | speed -> velocidade da passagem de slides em ms (milisegundos)
function Slider(item_class,slides,speed){

        let count = 1;
        // Mostrar o primeiro slide | Show first slide
        var iclass = item_class+"[data-slide=1]";
        $(iclass).show();

        // Efeito Zoom-in | Zoom-in Effect
        $( iclass+" img" ).animate( { zoom: "1.3" },6000 );

        function initSlider(max){

                var main_class = $(item_class);

                // Esconder slide antigo
                main_class.each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('data-slide') == count){
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                });

                // Incrementar Contagem de Slider | Increment Slide Count
                count++;

                // Verificar se passou o máximo de slides | Check if max slider is reached
                if(count > max){
                    count = 1;
                }else{
                    //count++;
                }    

                // Mostrar slide novo | Show new slide
                main_class.each(function(){
                    if($(this).attr('data-slide') == count){
                        $(this).slideDown("medium");
                        // Efeito Zoom-in | Zoom-in Effect
                        $( this ).find("img").animate( { zoom: "1" },0 );
                        $( this ).find("img").animate( { zoom: "1.3" },6000 );

                    }
                });

                //console.log("Slide "+count);

        }

        // Loop | Slider Loop
        if(slides != 1){ window.setInterval(function () { initSlider(slides); }, speed); }
}
```

It works properly in Chrome, however in the other 2 browsers it seem not doing the zoom effect

Comment: Use some screenshots for more clearly.

Comment: Does not seem to be supported in [firefox](https://caniuse.com/#search=zoom)